# ImproperlyConfigured: Middleware module "django.middleware.csrf" does not define a "CsrfResponseMiddleware" class

Tags: python, django, middleware

I don't have this problem on my local development environment, but I just deployed the app with nginx + gunicorn (first time deploying an app) and I am getting this traceback whenever I try to make a request.

```
2012-01-21 22:24:36 [5712] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 96, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 51, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Middleware module "%s" does not define a "%s" class' % (mw_module, mw_classname))
ImproperlyConfigured: Middleware module "django.middleware.csrf" does not define a "CsrfResponseMiddleware" class
```

The following is a part of my settings.py file

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the server where you deployed has different version of Django (old one). Also Penthi is right, `CsrfResponseMiddleware` is for backward compatibility and should be removed. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#legacy-method.

Comment: Actually it should be the newest one, 1.3.1. I just installed it a few days ago. I went into the `csrf.py` file and found that the `CsrfResponseMiddleware` class is actually not defined in there...

Comment: Have you installed it from trunk? I've just downloaded 1.3.1 archive and `csrf.py` file has `CsrfResponseMiddleware`. But it was removed in trunk - https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/middleware/csrf.py?rev=15949

Comment: ahh yes... i got it from trunk... thought I was getting 1.3.1!

Answer (score 4):

In Django 1.4, you should remove the '`django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware`', because it can cause security problems.

Furthermore, two things must be done.

1. Add a `{% csrf_token %}` tag to your post form.
2. Use `RequestContext` instead of `Context` in all of your relative views.py files.

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.3, I have only django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware in my middlewares to get CSRF protection working